# How to save dynamic 2D array imported from csv?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, dynamic, import

I am making a code importing CSV files into `String` 2D array.

Since I intend to apply this code for other CSV files also, which have different number of columns and rows, I should use dynamic array.

But I don't know handle both importing & saving in dynamic 2D array at once.
Could you help me find what is wrong with my codes? It doesn't work.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DataImport_1 {

   private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arr = null; 

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Dropbox (CMA)/1 Research (5)/TA/new Data/SPX Index.csv"));
      scanner.useDelimiter(",");

      arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); 

      child1 = new ArrayList<String>();

      while(scanner.hasNext()){
         child1.add(scanner.next());
      }
      arr.add(child1);
      child1.clear();
      scanner.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `Scanner.nextLine()` and split each line by comma or read the entire line (already splitted to columns) inside the while-loop. Right now you're doing neither!

Example for the first approach:

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/Dropbox (CMA)/1 Research (5)/TA/new Data/SPX Index.csv"));
  arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); 
  while(scanner.hasNext()){
     String line = scanner.nextLine();
     String[] columns = line.split(",");
     Collections.addAll(arr, columns); 
  }
  scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are structuring your `arr` as an array list of array lists, you need to create more than one `child1`.

As you "clear" `child1` it clears the object it refers to, which is the one you just stored in `arr`, and eventually you'll have a bunch of `arr` entries all referring to the same recently cleared `child1`.

For each row, instead of

```
child1.clear();
```

do

```
child1 = new ArrayList();
```